# How can I fix duplicate output using C#

Tags: c#, methods, passwords, stringbuilder

In the code below I am attempting to take a string and create a mock complex password. I have a couple methods that interact with two sets of user input. *Question Three* tests the "converter" method called `UserPassWord()`. In *Question Four*, I am taking user input and creating mock login information for the user using `Credentials()` method. However, the return statement in the `Credentials()` method keep giving me the generated passwords for both questions.

What can I do to be sure I am only returned the password for *Question Four* set of user input and method call. Thanks in advance.

```
//-------------------QUESTION THREE---------------------------------- -//
int MAXLENGTH = 8;
StringBuilder newString = new StringBuilder();

Console.WriteLine("Enter username to generate complex password");
string uname = Console.ReadLine();

string password = UserPassWord(uname);
Console.WriteLine(password);

//-------------------QUESTION FOUR---------------------------------- -//
Console.WriteLine("Enter Firstname");
string first = Console.ReadLine();

Console.WriteLine("Enter Lastname");
string last = Console.ReadLine();

string password1 = Credentials(first, last);

Console.WriteLine(password1);


//Method that applies to both question three and four
string UserPassWord(string username)
{
    string test = "";
    newString.Append(username);
    if (username.Length < MAXLENGTH)
    {
        CheckVowels();
        test = newString[0].ToString().ToUpper() + newString.ToString().Substring(1);
    }
    else if (username.Length > MAXLENGTH)
    {
        newString.Replace(username, username.Substring(0, MAXLENGTH));
        CheckVowels();
        test = newString[0].ToString().ToUpper() + newString.ToString().Substring(1);

    }
    return test;
}

string Credentials(string fname, string lname)
{
    StringBuilder userName = new StringBuilder();
    StringBuilder email = new StringBuilder();
    var testname = fname + lname;
    string suffix = "@oralacadamy.Test";

    userName.Append(fname);
    userName.Insert(fname.Length, ".");
    userName.Append(lname);

    var emailInfo = email.Append(fname.Substring(0).ToLower());
    email = emailInfo.Append(lname.ToLower());
    email.Append(suffix);

    string test = UserPassWord(testname);
    return $"Full Name: {testname}\nFull Name as password: {test}\nUser Name: {userName}\nEmail: {email}\nPassword: {test}";

}

void CheckVowels()
{
    char[] vowels = { 'a', 'e', 'i', 'o', 'u', 'A', 'E', 'I', 'O', 'U' };
    foreach (var vow in vowels)
    {
        newString = newString.Replace(vow, '*');
    }
}
```

Comment: Your `UserPassWord` method is manipulating `newString`? Should that be a local variable?

Comment: If I make it a local variable it will be out of scope for CheckVowels(). Do yo suggest I make it local and change CheckVowels() way of achieving its result.

Comment: Rename `CheckVowels` too, as it isn't checking anything. `string MaskVowels(string input)  /* implementation that returns the masked input */ }`

Comment: _newString_ is never _cleared_ between the first method and the second. Given the fact that you truncate the _newString_ content to _MAX_LENGTH_ you get always the first _MAX_LENGTH_ characters in the stringbuilder.